# Can you alter string characters without a loop?

Tags: string, assembly, mips

Me and my classmates are working on an assignment to manipulate strings in MIPS, and we were wondering if its possible to alter the characters in the string without looping through each byte individually? That is to say, can we go to an index in a string directly? It doesn't seem possible but I don't know mips that well, so maybe it is.

```
#assume I have a function that returns the length of the string with a newline
#the purpose of this is to find the newline and take it out

li $s0,0                     # Set index to 0
subi $s2,$v0,1           # set loop limit to length - 1(where the new   line character is)
loop2:
#iterate through string until we reach the newline character
beq $s0,$s2, done
la $a0, 1($a0)           # moves byte address of input along with loop counter to allow for correct placement of null terminator
add $s0,$s0,1            # loop counter 
j loop2

done:
#returns to first call of _readString
 sb $zero, ($a0)  #replaces newline with null terminator
 jr $ra
```

Comment: It would help to see an example of the code you're using now to loop through the characters. It seems like this should be a simple matter of adding an offset to the address of the string.

Comment: The thing is that the string is composed of user input and the length of the string isnt known untill runtime.

Comment: Again, it would be handy to know what you're looking at now. Why do you want to index inside a string of unknown length? Before accepting user input, you should set aside some known amount of memory for it.

Comment: I don't include it in the code segment but all input has a buffer set aside

Comment: Ok, wait. You have the length in `$v0`? What then is the purpose of `$s0`?  It seems like (I don't have a device I feel comfortable doing assembly on in front of me) you should be able to just say `la $a0, $s2($a0)` and be done.

Comment: I use $s0 as a counter to use to check when to branch when it reaches the length -1. And i dont think you can put a register as the offset for la. That was one of the first things we tried except we used a buffer like : la $a0, buffer($a0)

Comment: That's interesting. Can you add an arbitrary number to `$a0`? `add $a0, $a0, $v0`?